# How to remove the Elevation from the Tablayout?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

We created today A tablayout, but we have a Problem, the tablayout has elevation (or the linear in the top?)

anyways how we can remove the elevation? (btw it is our first app)

the code in the activty:

```
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout_id);
        appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar_id);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.AddFragment(new Tab1(), "Watching");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Tab2(), "Completed");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Tab3(), "Droped");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Tab4(), "On hold");
        adapter.AddFragment(new Tab5(), "Plan to watch");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }



}
```

and the code In ViewpagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> FragmentListTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
        super(supportFragmentManager);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return FragmentListTitles.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return FragmentListTitles.get(position);
    }

    public  void  AddFragment(Fragment fragment, String Title) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        FragmentListTitles.add(Title);

    }
}
```

[image: The Screenshot]

Im new soo plz dont kill me :/

Comment: Can you add your `layout` xml?

Comment: its not working :/ - edit: worked thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `app:elevation` to `0dp` in your `toolbar` like below:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: thanks, and do you know how to change the selected text color and the unselected?, cuz in my code is all of it in White

Comment: Please add another post with that problem, I will help you. Actually In *SO*, it’s recommended to ask one question per post. Hope you understand. Thanks